# Camel Netty4 udp Multicast not working on windows

Tags: java, apache-camel, netty

I have been trying to get the Camel Netty4 udp multicast to work on windows and the NettyUDPMulticastAsyncTest seems to be failing with a java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException.
The same test seems to be working on OSX. Both the machines are running Java 1.7
I have updated the interface name in the test and i am able to run a NIO UDP multicast sample on the same interface. 
I am using Camel 2.14.1 but it does not seem to be working on 2.15.x as well.

The stack trace is below.

```
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 0.026 sec <<< FAILURE! - in org.apache.camel.component.netty4.NettyUDPMulticastAsyncTest
testUDPInOnlyMulticastWithNettyConsumer(org.apache.camel.component.netty4.NettyUDPMulticastAsyncTest)  Time elapsed: 0.023 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.nio.channels.ClosedChannelException: null
        at sun.nio.ch.DatagramChannelImpl.innerJoin(DatagramChannelImpl.java:832)
        at sun.nio.ch.DatagramChannelImpl.join(DatagramChannelImpl.java:894)
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioDatagramChannel.joinGroup(NioDatagramChannel.java:409)
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioDatagramChannel.joinGroup(NioDatagramChannel.java:382)
        at io.netty.channel.socket.nio.NioDatagramChannel.joinGroup(NioDatagramChannel.java:375)
        at org.apache.camel.component.netty4.SingleUDPNettyServerBootstrapFactory.startServerBootstrap(SingleUDPNettyServerBootstrapFactory.java:177)
        at org.apache.camel.component.netty4.SingleUDPNettyServerBootstrapFactory.doStart(SingleUDPNettyServerBootstrapFactory.java:97)
        at org.apache.camel.support.ServiceSupport.start(ServiceSupport.java:61)
        at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:74)
        at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startService(ServiceHelper.java:59)
        at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startServices(ServiceHelper.java:103)
        at org.apache.camel.util.ServiceHelper.startServices(ServiceHelper.java:89)
        at org.apache.camel.component.netty4.NettyConsumer.doStart(NettyConsumer.java:69)
```

Comment: Check that windows firewall is not blocking the requests

Comment: The Firewall is turned off and i am able to join a multicast group from a different application from the same system.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the problem to be in binding to a multicast address before joining the group, which for some reason does not work on windows. Had to update the  bootstrap.bind to look like this in **SingleUDPNettyServerBootstrapFactory**

> ChannelFuture channelFuture = bootstrap.bind(new InetSocketAddress(configuration.getPort()));